# How to define class in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a class in Python and use it in bpython, but none of the examples that I've found have worked successfully and I can't figure out why.

In fubar.py:

```
class Fubar:
   def fubar():
      print 'fubar'
```

In bpython:

```
>>> import fubar
>>> Fubar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Fubar' is not defined
```

Why bpython? Because it supports history and tab-completion OOB.

Every example of python class definitions I've found looks like a variant of what I've used, which is why I don't understand why Fubar() is undefined. Thoughts, comments?

Python 2.6.5 (I don't get to pick the Python version in use)
bpython 0.9.5.2

I come from a Ruby background, if that helps explain the confusion to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current code is importing the *module* `fubar` that contains the class `Fubar`.  However, Python does not implicitly know this.  Instead, you have to explicitly tell it where `Fubar` is.

To do so, make your code like this:

```
fubar.Fubar()
```

Or, change your import-statement to this:

```
from fubar import Fubar
Fubar()  # This will now work
```

Here is a reference on [importing](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt).